# Virtual Host with multiple zend modules

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, virtualhost

I have installed the zend skeleton application and it works fine until I add multiple modules to it.  The problem is with the virtual hosts I have set up.  The scenario is as follows:

I have two sites: `cms.localhost` and `site.localhost`.
Both these virtual hosts are pointed to the same public folder however I want each to use their respective modules. Is there a virtual host directive I can use to tell `cms.localhost` to use the `Cms` module and the `site.localhost` to use the `Site` module I have setup in my zend project?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the hostname route type to achieve this. You can read on it [here in the documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-hostname). Here is an example for your case to get you started:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'cms' => array(
            'type' => 'hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => 'cms.localhost',
                'defaults' => array(
                   '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Cms\Controller',
                   'controller' => 'Index',
                   'action' => 'index',
                )
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // your cms child routes
            )
        ),
        'site' => array(
            'type' => 'hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => 'site.localhost',
                'defaults' => array(
                   '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Site\Controller',
                   'controller' => 'Index',
                   'action' => 'index',
                )
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // your site child routes
            )
        )
    )
),
```

In this example I used the `'__NAMESPACE__'` option to set a default namespace for the respective host names.

Comment: @CraigStandish I updated my answer, I forgot to wrap it in an array with key `'options'`...